# Behaviour MSBuild in VisualStudio 2015 differs from MSBuild in Console

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, custom-build-step

Affects: Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2015

When I start a build on my project in the VS-Solution it compiles all the project's source files. If I do it again and I have nothing changed, the build is up to date. But if I build from console like:

```
msbuild c:\path\to\my\project\my-project.vcxproj /t:build /p:configuration=Debug /p:Platform=Win32 /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0.25425.01
```

... the sources will be compiled again. (By building again in console, the build is up to date, too. On building after a console-build in VS, the build compiles all the project's source files.)

I noticed that my VS-Version (14.0.25425.01) differs from the showing console output (14.0.25420.1), so I added the `/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0.25425.01`-Parameter.
But this did nothing (even the console's output is still to `Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 14.0.25420.1`).
Maybe this can be the problem? But if, How do i fix it?

I also noticed via the Windows TaskManager, that the *MSBuild.exe*-Runtime started by Visual Studio will be active until VS is exited. (In my console, the *MSBuild.exe*-runtime ends, when the build has finished.)

Another curious thing i've noticed is, that in my console sometimes *MSBuild.exe* is started from *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE* (as always from Visual Studio) and sometimes *MSBuild.exe* is started from *C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin*. By comparing those files, they're identical.

Comment: Use the /verbosity:detailed option to find out why it decided to rebuild.

Comment: Uuhh.... TMI...
I noticed at the first difference at the target `CustomBuild` the line `Forcing rebuild of all source files due to a change in the command line since the last build.` (and then some uic'ing and moc'ing from Qt-Custom-Build-Steps begin to work) even though the previous output says `All files are up to date`.

Comment: I've found Issue [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888014/visual-studio-custom-build-event-always-executing) and added manually the output file to _Additional Dependencies_ from the build step with no effect.